# How can I add a DNS record so that example.com resolves to my server.example.com in the OS X Server app?

Tags: server.app, dns, domain

The default DNS setup leaves me with a record pointing server.example.com to my IP address. I've added a couple of aliases like www, mail.

But how can I add example.com, essentially the root domain so that when I type example.com in the web browser my web server gives me the page?

For example some DNS providers use a special syntax @.example.com -> server.example.com to specify the requests need to go there.

PS. Server is already configured to use itself as the a DNS.

<sup>OS X Server 4</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added a machine record (e.g. server.example.com) the primary zone example.com has been already created automagically.

To view all records (including your primary and the reverse zone) click on the gear near the bottom of the window and choose 'View All Records'.

Comment: True! However when I enter http://example.com in a web browser I get an error, if I enter a http://server.example.com I get the wiki website. Something is clearly missing somewhere.

Comment: Two things need to happen here:

First, you need the "." record in your example.com DNS zone file by adding
`.        <your servers IP address>`
in your example.com zone file. That is how it's done with BIND.

Second, your wiki needs to be configured that it not only listens on server.example.com but also on example.com. If you need to do this, I do not know. With the apache webserver, you need to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Garex The wiki already answers on any interface available. Added an A record for example.com to my IP. Seems to work. I thought there was some checkbox way to do this.

Comment: @unmircea You are right, I forgot to add a `. IN A <IP Adress>` in your zone file...